# Left Join and get only specific column with 1st string match in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables as data frames

T1

```
id  value1.   value2   
1.  hello.    34
1.  world.    55
1.  hai.      65
2.  universe. 67
3.  today.    89
3.  Country.  21
4.  Computer. 66
5.  Mouse.    45
```

I have another table T2

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Expected output

```
id  value1
1.  hello
2.  universe
3.  today
4.  computer
5.  mouse 
6.
7.
```

I tried merge which gives me all columns in T1. But I only want the column value1. and How can I only retrieve the first value of the match found?

NOTE: It should not drop duplicates in T2

Comment: There are no duplicates in T2... But if there were would the second 1 get joined with 'world' or still 'hello'? If 'world', none of the current solutions will work and you'll instead need to create a `cumcount` level and merge on both `ID` and the cumcount within each ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop duplicates based on `id` using [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates) from T1 then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) both dataframe on `id` by `right` and at last fill `NaN` with blank `''` by [`filna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```py
pd.merge(df.iloc[:,:2].drop_duplicates('id'), df1, on='id', how='right').fillna('')

   id    value1
0   1     hello
1   2  universe
2   3     today
3   4  Computer
4   5     Mouse
5   6          
6   7
```

Comment: It should not drop the duplicates in T2 Table

Comment: here, it's droping from T1

Answer (score 3):

We can try with [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) selecting `id` and `value1` columns and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to keep only the first (`keep == 'first'` by default) :

```
T2.merge(T1.drop_duplicates('id')[['id','value1']], how='left')


   id     value1
0   1      hello
3   2   universe
4   3      today
6   4   Computer
7   5      Mouse
8   6        NaN
9   7        NaN
```

Comment: It shoudl not drop duplicates in T2

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the duplicate indexes in T1

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='first', inplace=False)
```

after that just join it with T2